# MenuProcessor Configuration contains invalid Arguments

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I changed some configuration from backend and it causes the error.
[image]

I have just edited some URLs like URL for logo and favicon etc from `Backend -> Template -> Constant Editor -> Category -> Bootstrap Package: Logo (dropdown option)`. It causes to generate the error.

I reverted back the whole setting but it does work. I don't know what to do? Can anyone help me out?

Backend screenshot fromwhere I have edited some options.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing lot of r&d I have found the issue causing the problem. There was a TypoScript configuration is added into `Include Page TSConfig (from extensions)`. There were some more but specifically when I have removed the `Bootstrap Package: All Content Elements (bootstrap_package)` solved my problem. This option can be found on `Page properties -> Resources`. Also attached a

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems your TypoScript configuration for the MenuProcessor is invalid.

**Please check your configuration for something like:**

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
10 {
    references
}
```

The **references** key is not allowed here like the exception mentioned.

Should work again if you just remove it.

Comment: Yes. I have have found this but that was not the issue. I am posting the solution my self. But tank you for the solution.